# Toal canvas memory use exceeds by using openlayer map

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers to display a map on my website. I have different "markers" that will also be applied on the map based on Latitude and Longitude. This is my curent code:

```
const urlArgs = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)
const layersToUse = 5;

const disposeInternal = VectorTileLayer.prototype;

let customFeatures = {}
let toiletFeatures = []
let gastroFeatures = []

let allFeatures = {}

function addToLayer(mt, pt) {
    let ft = new Feature({
        geometry: new Point(
            fromLonLat([
                parseFloat(pt.longitude),
                parseFloat(pt.latitude)
            ])
        ),
        name: mt.name,
        iconUrl: mt.image,
        popupText: mt.popup_text,
        popupLinkText: mt.popup_link_text,
        popupLink: mt.popup_link,
    });

    if (mt.imported_type === "toilet") {
        toiletFeatures.push(ft)
    } else if (mt.imported_type === "gastro") {
        gastroFeatures.push(ft)
    } else {
        if (customFeatures[mt.marker_index % layersToUse] === undefined) {
            customFeatures[mt.marker_index % layersToUse] = [];
        }
        customFeatures[mt.marker_index % layersToUse].push(ft)
    }
    key = pt.longitude+"/"+pt.latitude;
    allFeatures[key] = ft;
}

let htmlMarkers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('marker'))
markers.forEach(
    (mt) => {
        Array.from(mt.points).forEach(
            (pt) => {
                addToLayer(mt, pt)
            }
        )
    }
)

let customSources = [];
for (let i = 0; i < layersToUse; i++) {
    customSources.push(
        new VectorSource({
            features: customFeatures[i]
        })
    )
}


let toiletSource = new VectorSource({
    features: toiletFeatures,
    cacheSize: 10,
})

let gastroSource = new VectorSource({
    features: gastroFeatures,
    cacheSize: 10,
})

let toiletLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: toiletSource,
    style: (feat) => {
        return new Style({
            image: new Icon({
                anchorOrigin: "bottom-left",
                anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                src: feat.get("iconUrl"),
            })
        })
    },
    declutter: true
})

let gastroLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: gastroSource,
    style: (feat) => {
        return new Style({
            image: new Icon({
                anchorOrigin: "bottom-left",
                anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                src: feat.get("iconUrl"),
            })
        })
    },
    declutter: true
})

let customLayers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < layersToUse; i++) {
    customLayers.push(
        new VectorLayer({
            source: customSources[i],
            style: (feat) => {
                return new Style({
                    image: new Icon({
                        anchorOrigin: "bottom-left",
                        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                        width: 35,
                        height: 35,
                        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                        anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                        src: feat.get("iconUrl"),
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    );
}

let zoneSource = new VectorSource({
    url: '/static/map_assets/map_zones.kml',
    cacheSize: 10,
    format: new KML({
        extractStyles: false
    }),
})

let zoneLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: zoneSource,
    style: (feat) => {
        const zoneColors = {
            "zone_1": 'rgba(244, 174, 108, 0.6)',
            "zone_2": 'rgba(227, 148, 193, 0.6)',
            "zone_3": 'rgba(161, 140, 217, 0.6)',
            "zone_gastro": 'rgba(115, 211, 121, 0.6)',
            "zone_arena": 'rgba(198, 26, 12, 0.8)',
            "zone_industrie": 'rgba(253, 215, 64, 1)',
        }
        return new Style({
            fill: new Fill({
                color: zoneColors[feat.id_],
            })
        })
    },
})

const klotenBaseView = new View({
    center: fromLonLat([8.57303, 47.46117]),
    rotation: -0.7,
    constrainRotation: true,
    zoom: 16,
    minZoom: 16,
    maxZoom: 18,
    // Matches full map size at minZoom
    extent: [952802.0356325043, 6016519.755591137, 955663.7673070097, 6018872.403698619]
})

let zoomCtrl = new Zoom()
let attribution = new Attribution()

const map = new olMap({
    controls: [zoomCtrl, attribution],
    target: 'map-container',
    layers: [
        new VectorTileLayer({
            declutter: true,
            preload: 0,
            source: new VectorTileSource({
                projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                format: new MVT(),
                url: 'pbf_url',
                maxZoom: 14,
                cacheSize: 10,
            })
        })
    ],
    view: klotenBaseView,
});

apply(
    map,
    "style.json_url"
).then((t) => {


    map.getLayers().extend([
        zoneLayer,
        toiletLayer,
        gastroLayer
    ]);
    customLayers.forEach((l) => {
        map.addLayer(l);    
    });
})

if (urlArgs.get("lat") && urlArgs.get("lon")) {
    let urlPos = fromLonLat([
        parseFloat(urlArgs.get("lon")),
        parseFloat(urlArgs.get("lat"))]
    );
    for(var key in allFeatures) {
        var value = allFeatures[key];
        var lat_long = key.split("/");
        var lat = parseFloat(lat_long[1]);
        var lon = parseFloat(lat_long[0]);
        var featLatLong = fromLonLat([lon, lat]);
        if (toStringXY(featLatLong) === toStringXY(urlPos)) {
            if (value && value.getGeometry().getType() === "Point") {
                showModal(
                    value.get("name"),
                    value.get("popupText"),
                    value.get("popupLinkText"),
                    value.get("popupLink")
                )
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    map.once('postrender', function() {
        var centerPx = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(urlPos);
        var newCenterPx = [centerPx[0] , centerPx[1]+ 80];
        var newCenter = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(newCenterPx);
        klotenBaseView.setCenter(newCenter);
        // klotenBaseView.setCenter(fromLonLat(urlLongLat));
        klotenBaseView.setZoom(18)

    });
}

let lastZoom = map.getView().getZoom()

map.on('moveend', (_event) => {
    let newZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    if (newZoom < 17.3) {
        gastroLayer.setVisible(false)
        customLayers.forEach((l) => {l.setVisible(false)})
        
    } else if (newZoom > 17.3) {
        gastroLayer.setVisible(true)
        customLayers.forEach((l) => {l.setVisible(true)})
    }
    lastZoom = newZoom
})

map.on('click', (event) => {

    if (event.pixel) {
        const clickedFeat = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feat) => {
            return feat
        })
        if (clickedFeat && clickedFeat.getGeometry().getType() === "Point") {
            showModal(
                clickedFeat.get("name"),
                clickedFeat.get("popupText"),
                clickedFeat.get("popupLinkText"),
                clickedFeat.get("popupLink")
            )
        }
    event.preventDefault()
    }
})

map.once('rendercomplete', (event => {
    const areaSelectors = document.querySelectorAll('.area_selector')

    areaSelectors.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            const zoneFeature = zoneSource.getFeatureById(el.dataset.zone)
            const zonePoly = zoneFeature.getGeometry()
            klotenBaseView.fit(zonePoly)
        })
    })

    if (urlArgs.get("zone")) {
        const zoneFeature = zoneSource.getFeatureById(urlArgs.get("zone"))
        const zonePoly = zoneFeature.getGeometry()
        klotenBaseView.fit(zonePoly)
    }

}))
```

And this map works fine on all browsers, except safari on iOS. The problem I am getting is following:

```
Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (384 MB).
```

I know Safari has some weird problems with canvas-caching, and I looked up urls like [this one](https://pqina.nl/blog/total-canvas-memory-use-exceeds-the-maximum-limit/) but I have no idea where to do what in my code to fix this, and it is quite important. Does anybody know anything about this issue?

Comment: IOS has a smaller canvas quota than other systems.  Which version of OpenLayers are you using?  The latest version attempts to recycle canvas, older version did not.  Also using `renderMode: 'vector',` on the vector tile layers will reduce canvas use.

Comment: The `renderMode: 'vector'`, unfortunately didn't work, the map still doesn't render after a few visits. The version I am using is 7.3.0